# Where can I find o365 2016 msi version?

Tags: office-addins, outlook-web-addins, outlook-2016

I have an o365 addin that works as expected on click 2 run versions of Outlook, however, there is a customer that has a MSI installation of Outlook 2016 that experiences inconsistencies.

I would like to obtain a copy of Outlook 2016 MSI so that I can do some testing locally.

It may be an issue with centralized deployment but would like to do some validation.

I've done web searches and contacted MS support. All things lead to MSI versions no longer being available.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @AStopher thank you, very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

May be the following will help you.

**Workaround:**
To get the MSI versions either you can remote their machine or get the MSI copy from customer (may not be feasible solution)

Understanding API requirement sets for Outlook.

I believe when the Addin was developed, you might be aware of the API requirement set. The following will be your case

> All Outlook APIs belong to the Mailbox requirement set. The Mailbox
> requirement set has versions, and each new set of APIs that are
> released belongs to a higher version of the set. **Not all Outlook
> clients will support the newest set of APIs when they are released**,
> but if an Outlook client declares support for a requirement set, it
> will support all the APIs in that requirement set.

**For example:**

if you specify requirement set version 1.3, the add-in will not show up in any Outlook client that doesn't support a minimum version of 1.3.

You can use the following code : isSetSupported property to check whether the addin is supported or not

```
if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('Mailbox', 1.3) === true) {
  // Perform actions.
}
else {
  // Provide alternate flow/logic.
}
```

**official reference:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/outlook-api-requirement-sets

[image]
[image]

From the above screenshot you can easily figure out which add in will work on which version.

Hope it will give some idea of how to solve your problem.